# AWS Redshift COPY csv from S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift

I have two doubts regarding AWS Redshift COPY command when use to load a CSV file from S3. I expected an error in these two conditions but didn't get an error and works fine. So help me to understand the working of COPY command in these conditions:

1. A required field is empty in CSV.
2. CSV has more columns than Redshift.

Comment: What do you mean by "required field"? Did you define the table with a column marked as `NOT NULL`? Can you show us the definition?

Comment: Yes, I meant required field as NOT NULL column.

Comment: [Loading Default Column Values - Amazon Redshift](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_loading_default_values.html) says: "If COPY attempts to assign NULL to a column that is defined as NOT NULL, the COPY command fails."  It might be treating the empty column as a blank string, as opposed to NULL.

Answer (score 0):

Working of COPY command in the above situations:

1. If the column is VARCHAR or CHAR, the field will be treated as Blank (it's not NULL) and will load the field as-is. If we want to treat blank as null use BLANKSASNULL parameter.
2. If the table contains fewer columns than the CSV, COPY command will skip the excess columns and load from left.